# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] at app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I dont know why off this error I have another model and almost the same route and the controllers but is not working this is the message:
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
at Route. [as get] (/Users/ediechavero/Documents/Recipe-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
at Function.proto. [as get] (/Users/ediechavero/Documents/Recipe-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:510:19)
at Object. (/Users/ediechavero/Documents/Recipe-API/routes/places-routes.js:22:8)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object. (/Users/ediechavero/Documents/Recipe-API/app.js:62:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (in

```
//Controllers places this is the controllers file for the crud places
const Place = require('../models/Place');

exports.getAllPlacess = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const places = await Place.find().populate('owner');
    res.status(200).json({ places });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `${error}` });
  }
};

exports.getPlace = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const place = await (await Place.findById(id)).populate('owner');
    res.status(200).json({ place });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `${error}` });
  }
};

exports.createPlace = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, typePlace, address } = req.body;
    const owner = req.user.id;

    const place = await Place.create({
      name,
      typePlace,
      address,
      owner,
    });
    res.status(201).json({ place });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `${error}` });
  }
};

exports.updatePlace = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { name, typePlace, address } = req.body;
    const place = await Place.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
      name,
      typePlace,
      address,
      owner,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ place });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `${error}` });
  }
};

exports.deletePlace = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    await Place.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted Recipe' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `${error}` });
  }
};



//Route this the file for the routes 
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const uploadConfig = require('../config/cloudinary');

const {
  getAllPlaces,
  getPlace,
  createPlace,
  updatePlace,
  deletePlace,
} = require('../controllers/places');

router.post('/upload', uploadConfig.single('photo'), (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    next(new Error('No file uploades'));
  }
  res.status(201).json({ secure_url: req.file.secure_url });
});

//CRUD PLACES

router.get('/places', getAllPlaces);
router.get('/places/:id', getPlace);
router.post('/places/create', createPlace);
router.put('/places/edit/:id', updatePlace);
router.delete('/places/delete/:id', deletePlace);

module.exports = router;

//app.js

require('dotenv').config();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const logger = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const colors = require('colors');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then((x) =>
    console.log(
      `Connected to Mongo! Database name: "${x.connections[0].name}"`.cyan
        .underline.bold
    )
  )
  .catch((err) => console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err.red));

const app_name = require('./package.json').name;
const debug = require('debug')(
  `${app_name}:${path.basename(__filename).split('.')[0]}`
);

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [process.env.FRONTENDPOINT],
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 },
  })
);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(logger('dev'));

const index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);

const recipe = require('./routes/recipe-routes');
app.use('/api', recipe);

const place = require('./routes/places-routes');
app.use('/api', place);

// Uncomment this line for production
// app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Which line of your code is this error occurring on?

Comment: line 22 in the route file router.get('/places',getAllPlaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a difference in spelling where you export and where you import.

You are defining one export as this:

```
exports.getAllPlacess = function() { ... }
```

But, then importing it as this:

```
const {
  getAllPlaces,
  getPlace,
  createPlace,
  updatePlace,
  deletePlace,
} = require('../controllers/places');
```

---

Change this:

```
exports.getAllPlacess = function() { ... }
```

to this:

```
exports.getAllPlaces = function() { ... }
```

Comment: @EdieAprovita - If this answered your question or solved your problem, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.