In my Node JS Express server, I got this error where it says "Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]"
The whole error message says:
D:\directory\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:216
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (D:\directorynode_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:216:15)
    at proto.<computed> [as post] (D:\directory\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:521:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\directory\routes\searchRoutes.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\directory\index.js:7:22)

My index.js is structured like this:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./database/db');
const roleRoutes = require('./routes/roleRoutes');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const searchRoutes = require('./routes/searchRoutes');


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.use('/search', searchRoutes);
app.use('/', userRoutes); // Assuming userRoutes handles '/' route
app.use('/', roleRoutes); // Assuming roleRoutes handles '/' route

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({Messsage: 'NCF Repository Backend Running!'});
});

// Define a catch-all route handler for undefined routes
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({ message: 'Route not found' });
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Also, my searchRoutes is structured like this:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const fuseController = require('../controllers/fuseSearch');
const fuzzballController = require('../controllers/fuzzballSearch');

router.post('/fuse', fuseController.fuseSearch);
router.post('/fuzzball', fuzzballController.fuzzballSearch);

module.exports = router;

Therefore, I can't exactly distinguish what's happening, as I've tried several ways to get rid of that error and nothing works for me.

Your question doesn't contain enough information to help you please also include what is present in fuseController and fuzzballController?. You can either provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or contents of both the controllers to better help your case

See if this solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217991/error-route-get-requires-a-callback-function-but-got-a-object-undefined-at?rq=2

Looks like fuseController.fuseSearch is not a function.

@keith is right; your fuseController is not a function. Try to first verify that it's a function or a class, or that you have missed something in the code.
